# How to gracefully shut down (SIGTERM) an Apollo Server instance?

Tags: node.js, express, apollo, sigterm

The actual HTTP server instance can be killed with [`server.close(callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback), but I'm not sure what will happen with any pending WebSocket operations (mutations or queries being run through WebSockets). Since http.Server doesn't really know anything about the WebSocket operations, it probably ignores them. How to properly make sure that when SIGTERM is received, the server stops accepting new requests/webSocket connections, finishes the pending ones and then closes?

Couldn't really find anything about this with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming based on the year this question was asked that you are asking about ApolloServer v2. Apollo Server instance does provide `stop` function which as [per documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/api/apollo-server) waits for all the background tasks running. So it will wait for existing queries to complete before terminating the server. The method is [available for v3](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server#stop) as well.

> `ApolloServer.stop()` is an async method that tells all of Apollo
> Server's background tasks to complete. It calls and awaits all
> [`serverWillStop` plugin
> handlers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/integrations/plugins/#serverwillstop)
> (including the [usage reporting
> plugin](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/api/plugin/usage-reporting)'s
> handler, which sends a final usage report to Apollo Studio). This
> method takes no arguments.
>
> If your server is a [federated
> gateway](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/gateway/),
> `stop` also stops gateway-specific background activities, such as
> polling for updated service configuration.
>
> In some circumstances, Apollo Server calls `stop` automatically when
> the process receives a `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` signal. See the
> [`stopOnTerminationSignals` constructor
> option](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/api/apollo-server#stoponterminationsignals)
> for details.
>
> If you're using the `apollo-server` package (which handles setting up
> an HTTP server for you), this method first stops the HTTP server.
> Specifically, it:
>
> - Stops listening for new connections
> - Closes idle connections (i.e., connections with no current HTTP request)
> - Closes active connections whenever they become idle
> - Waits for all connections to be closed
>
> If any connections remain active after a grace period (10 seconds by
> default), Apollo Server forcefully closes those connections. You can
> configure this grace period with the [`stopGracePeriodMillis`
> constructor
> option](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/api/apollo-server#stopgraceperiodmillis).
>
> If you're using a [middleware
> package](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/integrations/middleware)
> instead of `apollo-server`, you should stop your HTTP server before
> calling `ApolloServer.stop()`.